# Can't hide rows and columns with Python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to write a little script that is going to hide rows and columns. The problem is - I can hide one row or one column like this:

```
ws.column_dimensions['F'].hidden = True # The same for row
```

But when I was trying to hide much more rows and columns, it just doesn't work. For example:

```
for i in range(112, ws3.max_row + 1):
    ws3.row_dimensions[i].hidden = True
```

So, basically, from what you can see, what I want to do, is to just hide all rows starting from 112. And everything I can tell, that it just doesn't work and I don't actually know why (I have no error or something, as a result of my program, I get just normal file, but columns or rows are not hidden or deleted), probably because of quantity of rows.

So, is there any other way to **hide or delete** rows and columns from sheet?

Comment: What do you mean with "it just doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? If yes, please share the traceback. Or are you simply not getting your expected result? Also, please share a minimum reproducible code

Comment: Are you saving the changed worksheet after making the changes? Changes above are applied to the in-memory representation and must be saved calling `b.save()`

Comment: @CodeMonkey Yes, I definitely do.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine as long as there are more than 111 rows (ws3.max_row). Are you looking at the right sheet? `ws` vs. `ws3`. Does `ws3` have more than 111 rows. Print and check `i` and `ws3.max_row` values. Hope the file is saved to correct file as already asked....

Comment: @Redox The sheet is correct. What I found is that `ws.max_row` and `ws.max_column` show me rows and columns that is filled with content. So, if (from `A1`) I have table 110 rows x 10 columns it shows `max_row = 110` and `max_column = 10`.

Comment: Do you mean that ws3.max_row + 1 is 110 + 1 or 111? So the for statement **for i in range(112, ws3.max_row + 1):** would do nothing...

Comment: @moken Right, this is what I am talking about, seems like `ws3.max_row` doesn't return the real max quantity of row, but quantity of rows, where I have content, just like in example with table I wrote before.

Comment: Yes its not a quantity it is the last row in the sheet that has data. So if you have a value in cell A1 and A100 the result is 100 not 2.